# Camel / AggregationStrategy after tokenizeXML

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I want to know the number of order saved after split().tokenizeXML

i have a xml

```
<orders>
 <order>
 ....
```

my route

```
.split().tokenizeXML("order")
 .unmarshal("xmlbsondataformat")
 .beanRef("orderShopConnector", "saveOrder")
```

in my bean orderShopConnector, i add in header properties saveOK=1.

```
headers.put("ordersave",1);
```

now, I want know the sum of the order saved, in the firstexchange properties.
I think use AggregationStrategy but i canot see how to use after tokenizeXML, it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the examples at the Camel docs, and you can see how to use a tokenizer and aggregation strategy together: http://camel.apache.org/splitter, for example at the *Split aggregate request/reply sample* example.

Comment: yes I am using this example and camelinaction, but the problem i cannot use Aggregation Strategy with tokenizeXML.  split(body().tokenizeXML("order"), i haven't got function tokenizeXML( after body(). i can use tokenizeXML only after split().tokenizeXML() so i cannot place AggregationStrategy.I use java dsl. So My main question is : where i place AggrationStrategy with java dsl and tokenizeXML()? thank Claus ;-)

Comment: Use the static import of org.apache.camel.language.tokenizer.TokenizeLanguage#tokenizeXML

Comment: Logged a ticket to have tokenizeXML out of the box on the body() - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6422

Comment: Thank Claus, how i can use the static import in my example. i add line import static org.apache.camel.language.tokenizer.TokenizeLanguage.tokenizeXML;

Comment: Then use tokenizeXML instead of body(), eg split(tokenizeXML(a, b), new MyAggStrategy())